# remove deteriorating lining from a jacket

Tags: clothing

I have a beloved jacket whose lining unfortunately began deteriorating after running it through the wash. I tried contacting the manufacturer but they did not offer any help since the jacket is too old and discontinued.

So now I've turned the jacket inside out and am trying to remove the lining completely. I'm not sure exactly what substance the lining is made of, perhaps some kind of urethane.

What methods can I use to remove the lining?

So far I've scrubbed an area with a scouring pad, which works but is very difficult and time consuming. Is there any chemical or mechanical method that would be more efficient?

[image]

Comment: as an update, I eventually continued with the scouring pad for a few hours and removed the rest by abrasion

Answer (score 1):

You should try heat. This white lining looks like a substance glued to the fabric. Most fabric glues melt above 40°C / 104°F.

Heat a patch of fabric with a blow dryer for a minute, then try peeling it off. Or stick a piece of duct tabe onto the lining and peel it off.

If you want to combine heat and tape, first heat the fabric, then put the tape on. Do not heat the tape or the glue might get stuck on your jacket.

Answer (score 0):

You could test a small area with denatured alcohol, or rubbing alcohol. Some kind of solvent should dissolve it, but be careful that it doesn't also dissolve the rest of the jacket.

Answer (score 0):

I sprayed mine with a goo remove orange spray, let it sit for an hour, then washed it on a hot wash and presto it is all gone, I can either respray it or leave it and use it as a wind jacket. Very happy with the result.De